# .htaccess Magento stopping access to other sites on server

Tags: index

I have a mutliple magento site on a Shared Server. I appeciate that this is not ideal at all to share site on a shared server as the resources are limited, however its working ok.

I have to have the .htaccess file  in the route of my server, however my sites in in sub folders

Site1.com looks at
**TheServerRoute/Website/Website1/**

Site2.com looks at
**TheServerRoute/Website/Website2/**

This works perfectly, however if I want to throw a standard site on the same server, HTML or PHP (not magento) i get issues.

Basically i put the site at
**TheServerRoute/Website/Website3/**

if i navigate to Site3.com i get nothing, 404 server error, if I navigate to Site3.com/index.html it will show the html page I made, equally if i go to Site3.com/index.php it will show the php page I made. I think this is related to my .htaccess folder rewriting things or something like that, so index files do not automatically show when navigating to a folder. Should the .htaccess that I have in my route, even be sat in my route? or should i have a file sat in the individual site routes (i.e. Website1 and Website2 folders) etc?

I am new to Linux and the use of .htacccess and somewhat lost...

I have tried
 - deleting the .htaccess files (clearly this messes up  my magento access)
 - deleting the .htaccess and placing a copy inside the relevant magento folders

Now I am a stuck for methods. Perhaps my understanding on a .htaccess file is wrong...

Hopefully you guys can help, and we can provide a resource for people to look at, as googling this came up with nothing...

Look forward to some thought, questions, comments and suggestions :)

**UPDATE**
I have narrowed it down to two areas in my .htaccess file. Either

```
## default index file
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
```

which i don't think is an issue, but

```
## rewrite everything else to index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

which i think is where the problem lies.

Is it possible to do a RewriteRule to html and then if this doesn't exist then try php?

Or am i just better off making a standard index.php file in each directory which redirects to the HTML version?

Comment: if you need any more information, feel free to ask, I could even provide a copy of the .htaccess file if you like, as there's nothing too sensitive in there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED IT !!

I had

```
## default index file
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
```

However I needed to include .HTML before the .PHP

```
## default index file
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
```

This sets the priority of index.html before index.php so it will load .html if it exists, then .php if it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

I would think this is caused by where you .htaccess file is.

You should store you .htaccess file here

```
TheServerRoute/Website/Website3/.htaccess
```

and then you should'nt have issues.

Comment: this .htaccess file is for the magento store rules, which are at TheServerRoute/Website/Website2/ but if I put the .htaccess file here, then my site doesnt work at all... or atleast the back end doesnt

Comment: could this be an issue with not having a reqwrite base in it? do i need to change 

`#RewriteBase /`

to

`RewriteBase /Website/Website2/`

Comment: why are you not using httpd.conf file in the apache conf folder?  This would be the correct place to set up virtual servers

Comment: Correction @Toby Allen, its a Shared server not a VPS, I have corrected my original post to reflect this, sorry for the confusion. My mistake